# Is it possible to fetch records from SQLite databse asynchronously

Tags: android, sqlite, asynchronous

I know that I can do my database commands in a separate thread to prevent "Not Responding" (Such as SELECT command in a table with a lot of records) and pass populated list to the main thread.

This is a sample of fetching records and it might take about two seconds due to number of records, now I want to know, is there any way to fetch records from tables asynchronously instead of "query" method.

```
public Word[] getWords(int rid) {

    Word[] returnVal = null;

    db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_WORDS, COLUMNS_WORDS, "RID=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(rid) }, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        returnVal = new Word[cursor.getCount()];

        do {
            // populate returnVal

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    cursor.close();

    return returnVal;
}
```

Comment: use a `CursorLoader`

Comment: did you solve your problem?

Comment: Sorry that I have not explained my mean well. I'm looking for a way to give me records when they found and not collecting and pass them as cursor. Is it possible?

Comment: I didnt get what you are asking\

Comment: @Amy Consider that I've 3 records in my table that 1, 3 are match with my query. Now I expect SQLite to return me record 1 once found it and continue search to found record 3. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: I am not sure but it seems it is not possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `AsyncTask` Class you can do this. Make another class which is exdending AsyncTask and call your method in overridden `doInBackground` method

```
class SQLAsyncTaskextends AsyncTask<String, String, String[]> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
           return getWords(rid); // Pass rid here
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
           //Do something with result
        }

 }
```